# Python. How do I saving python array output into an Sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi i am doing a rasbery project. I am new to this and new with python. I have a python code taking  luminaire lux levels reading from a light sensor. I Want to take these lux levels readings and save them into an Sqlite database table. the code i have for reading the lux is below

```
import smbus

import time

# Get I2C bus

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# BH1715 address, 0x23(35)

# Send power on command

#       0x01(01)    Power On

bus.write_byte(0x23, 0x01)

# BH1715 address, 0x23(35)

# Send continuous measurement command

#       0x10(16)    Set Continuous high resolution mode, 1 lux resolution, Time = 120ms

bus.write_byte(0x23, 0x10)

time.sleep(0.5)

# BH1715 address, 0x23(35)

# Read data back, 2 bytes using General Calling

# luminance MSB, luminance LSB

data = bus.read_i2c_block_data (0x23, 2)

# Convert the data

luminance = (data[0] * 256 + data[1]) / 1.2

# Output data to screen

print "Ambient Light luminance : %.2f lux" %luminance
```

i want to save the Luminance values as they come in into an Sqlite database table

Comment: What have you tried regarding Sqlite?

Comment: You can find the documentation of the `sqlite3` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Come up with a database schema - the tables and columns to hold your data - and then insert data into the table(s). Start by making a list of what information you want to record in the database.